# Invoking AWS Gateway API: com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException

Tags: aws-api-gateway

ers,

I am invoking the AWS Api but I am getting a

```
Endpoint response body before transformations: 
{"__type":"com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException"}
Endpoint response body before transformations:
{
"__type": "com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException"
}
```

Error after a specific post of the same type of jobs. I've enabled detailed Cloudwatch logging but it doesn't give me any additional information. Moreover, the concerned API request body  is truncated before and after transformations.

Are there some additional log options to test? I think I just have to take the original API call in JSON and remove fields from them in order to see what makes it break?

Comment: did you find any solution for this? I am also looking for solution for same while performing query operation via API Gateway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally fixed by providing the following mapping template in the integration request:

```
 #set($input = $input.json('$'))
  {
     "input": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input).replaceAll("\\'", "'")",
   "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:xxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
```

A bit of a nasty fix, but it worked...

Comment: hi, I'm strugling with similar issue. How did you end up knowing to do this particular replace? I can't see the response before transformation

Comment: Ah, I don't know where I found it, just after some heavy Googling I suspect. Sorry, can be quite a pain in the ** to fix.

Comment: Just curious - were you not using any MappingTemplate at all before, or did you instead correct your MappingTemplate (as here)?

Comment: For anyone finding this now, more documentation can be seen [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#util-template-reference).

`$util.escapeJavaScript` escapes *too much* of the JSON you supply because it captures and escapes `'` characters. The replacement then adds them back in.

Answer (score 8):

I was getting this error on a API Gateway REST API directly integrated with a DynamoDB table using a VTL mapping template. The error started after I changed the mapping template.

```
HTTP/2 200

{"__type":"com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException"}
```

Upon checking the mapping template JSON with an online '[JSON Validator](https://jsonlint.com/)' tool i found that my template wasnt valid JSON. (I had an extra `,` character in a list of objects). Fixing the template so that it was valid JSON fixed the error

Comment: Thanks. I was breaking my head for hours what is wrong. For anyone facing the same issue, please use this https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#. It validates and suggests correction to your json.

Comment: Thought there was no way I had an error in the template.  Welp, I was wrong.  Validating the JSON and then correcting the silly mistakes resolved my issue getting the SerializationException error.

Answer (score 3):

I had almost the same problem/exception-error:

I'm not sure if you, like me, **had no Mapping Template at all** while first experiencing the problem, but **providing one helps** obviously - of course its details need to satisfy the context of the AWS service that you are accessing via your Gateway API's `Integration Request` in order to ultimately solve this problem!  [As you have provided in your own Answer for your context].

If you didn't provide a Mapping Template, there's actually a log statement (soon after the `com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException`) that is indicative of that:

```
Endpoint request body after transformations:
```

See how there's no body listed there?  That's what seems to happen without a Mapping Template, which makes sense, as a Mapping Template would be the source of content for the body (no Mapping Template results in no request body there) - for example, the below Mapping Template JSON also ends up as being exactly the same (and being logged as such as the exact same JSON) for the `Endpoint request body after transformations` when using that Mapping Template (instead of no body to be printed as in the above log statement).

In my case for example, my `Integration Request` was for a **DynamoDB `GetItem`** (basically following this recent new tutorial for that, which has more details/screenshots than I've seen in others: https://medium.com/@likhita507/using-api-gateway-to-get-data-from-dynamo-db-using-without-using-aws-lambda-e51434a4f5a0).  My `Integration Request`'s `application/json` Mapping Template ended up successfully like this (just a table query by a specific value/tuple for its composite key):

```
{
  "TableName": "MyTableName",
  "Key": {
      "myPartitionKeyName": {"N" : "12345"},
      "mySortKeyName": {"N" : "12345"}
  }
}
```

[A DynamoDB Composite Key is the tuple pair of {< partition key >, < sortKey >}.  In my case they had the names `myPartitionKeyName` & `mySortKeyName`, and they were both a Number-type (yes, their `"12345"` values still get `"double-quoted"` for DynamoDB here, even though they aren't Strings).]

Anyways... you probably need to make sure you provide at least *some* Mapping Template (rather than none) - as well as it being a *sufficient* (whatever is required in your context) Mapping Template :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  There are many possible reasons it won't serialize correctly   `Endpoint request body after transformations: ` is the key place to look.
Templates are not valid json, but instead VTL  https://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work with

API Gateway Definition (Swagger):

```
requestTemplates:
                'application/json': '{"stateMachineArn":"YOUR_ARN","input":"$input.body"}'
```

Body for POSt Request (Notice the escaped quotes. Not single quote):

```
{\"test\":\"test\"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you input a invalid json input, like `{"fdf"}` instead of `{"2ee":"2ee"}`